# complex main branch of a logarithmic function holomorphic correct

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z:= x+iy$ It will now be shown that

$$f(z)= f(x+iy) =  \frac{1}{2} \log(x^2 + y^2) + i \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right); (z\in \mathbb{C}, x = \operatorname{Re} z \ne 0),$$

where $arctan$ denotes the main branch of the real $\arctan$ function and $\log$ the real logarithmic function, is (1) : a holomorphic function $(f(z)\in \mathcal{O}(G))$ and that it is (2): a logarithmic function, and also the main branch of the logarihmic function.

For (1): The Cauchy Riemann conditions are checked. $u_{x}=\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}} = v_{y}$ and $u_{y} = \frac{-y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} = -v_{x}$. Thus f(z) is holomorphic.

(2): A logarithmic function must satisfy $\exp(\log(z)) = z = re^{i\phi}$ And we see that with $\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2) = \log((x^{2}+y^{2})^{1/2})$ :

$$\exp(\log((x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}) + i\arctan(y/x)) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{i\arctan(y/x)} = |z|e^{i\phi} $$

and thus $f(z)$ must be a logarithmic function. Since only the main branch of the arctan function is allowed, that means that this is also the main branch of the complex logarithm.

**It wasn't shown here that $\arctan(y/x) = \phi$, how do I do that? Is it true that $f(z)$ is a logarithmic function only in the right half plane  ?**

Answer (score 1):

Its not only true that arg($x+iy$) $= \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ in the right half plane and you can show that by drawing a picture and using the pythagorean theorem. However, the complex logarithm is only holomorphic throughout the entire cut plane = $\{x+iy | x > 0$ or $y \neq 0)$ i.e., the entire complex plane minus the negative $x-$ axis and the origin. It is noted above that only the main branch of $\arctan$ is being used and thus only the main branch of the complex logarithm is being used as well.

It is true that this particular particular $f(z)$ is valid for the right half plane but it is not defined when $x=0$ since $\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ would not be defined. This is rectified by defining the domain of $f$ such that Re($z$) $\neq 0$.

Thus your function is holomorphic since it deletes points where $x = 0$ and presumes to use only the principle branch of the complex logarithm.